# Cannot launch phpmyadmin in ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I install apache2 and phpmyadmin but when i launch localhost/phpmyadmin i have this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCjsO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could have installed xampp or lampp but you might not have started the service.
How about you start the service from the terminal :
using:
 service /opt/lammp/xampp start
 then followed by:
service /opt/lampp/xampp status to check weather the service has started.

note this is for xampp else if you installed using lampp then you exclude the xampp

Comment: but I have install apache2 and php and phpmyadmin not install lamp but i have use apache2 and php and phpmyadmin